# Blogger dynamic template sometimes broken

Tags: blogger, template

In all browsers (IE, Chrome, etc.) in my office and in home and in all Blogger blogs using the dynamic template, I'm having this strange problem:

No menu on the right side (except for the Subscribe button - other buttons are missing) plus no layout selection bar (top row).

This problem is occasional, not happening reliably; any ideas?

[image: dynamic template error]

***Update*** (old news really, but I kind of forgot about the question):

The fix is to change the default timeout:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
      }, 500);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use a dynamic template, but I also never experienced such problem with blogs that use this template.

Try checking this in another PC, or with add-ons disabled and see if you have the same problem with other blogs such as this one http://buzz.blogger.com/

Anyway, the place to ask about this is on Google Blogger forums, they're the one who should support you with this. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/blogger

Comment: When I get this problem, it occurs in all browsers (including Safari with no addons) and with all blogs (including buzz.blogger.com - which I tried before). If I try it a bit later on the same computer, sometimes the problem is miraculously gone. I asked on the Google Forum but got no answer.

Comment: I were able to produce this problem by limiting my connection speed, but the problem solved with a refresh... I'm sorry I can't help you more with this, I think it could be a slow connection/loading problem...

Comment: For me Refresh doesn't help. But connection speed might be the issue in which case I'm shocked how ungracefully blogger handles it.

Comment: Ah, IMO the dynamic template is clumsy, well, somehow... testing it while limiting my connection speed, I noticed it does low too slowly, too slow for a webpage with no sidebar or extra elements... I always use my own template, it's pretty easy with Blogger to make your own, and you can have control over the page load time.